# Empty currently filled multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this :-

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ind_ava_1
                    [1] => ind_ava_2
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => varejo_bens_1
                    [1] => varejo_bens_2
                    [2] => varejo_bens_3
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [1] => fun_t1_2
                    [2] => fun_t1_3
                    [3] => fun_t1_4
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [1] => mar_ven_2
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => op_oper_1
                    [1] => op_oper_2
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [1] => op_org_2
                    [2] => op_org_3
                )

            [28] => Array
                (
                    [1] => op_risco_2
                )

            [30] => Array
                (
                    [0] => op_est_1
                )

        )
```

I want to remove every cell in it, as in remove [3], [5], etc etc. and make it empty before filling it up again. Any idea how I can do that?

I tried following:

```
         for($ctr = 0; $ctr < count($array); $ctr++) {

                  unset(data[$array]);
              }
```

Comment: Why don't you just `unset` the entire array and re-create it? It would have the same effect as your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a function on something that doesn't exist.  `data[$array]` is not a thing.

Assuming your array is called `$array` you can do `unset($array['data']);` and you don't need to run this in a loop.

PauloASilva's answer should work too.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
<?php
$data = array();
?>
```